# Shuffling Items in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, arrays, random, unity-game-engine, shuffle

I have this script of an array that shows a listing of items.

Now the thing is I only want this list to have five items shown out of ten and also shuffled, so you can't have the same list every time you start a new game

I was thinking if there should be a `Random.Range` implemented but I don't know where.

Please Help, and explain what should be done. I'm still a bit new to this and Thanks.

Here's the script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class RayCasting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float pickupDistance;
    public List<Item> items;

    #region Unity
    void Start ()
    {
        Screen.lockCursor = true;
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, pickupDistance))
        {
            foreach(Item item in items)
            {
                if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
                {
                    if (item.gameObject.Equals(hit.collider.gameObject))
                    {
                        numItemsCollected++;
                        item.Collect();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(130,400,100,100));
        {
            GUILayout.BeginVertical();
            {
                if (numItemsCollected < items.Count)
                {
                    foreach (Item item in items)
                    {
                        GUILayout.Label(string.Format("[{0}] {1}", item.Collected ? "" + item.password: " ", item.name ));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    GUILayout.Label("You Win!");
                }
            }
            GUILayout.EndVertical();
        }
        GUILayout.EndArea();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Private
    private int numItemsCollected;
    #endregion
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Item
{
    public string name;
    public GameObject gameObject;
    public int password;

    public bool Collected { get; private set; }

    public void Collect()
    {
        Collected = true;
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void passwordNumber()
    {
        password = 0;
        Collected = true;
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you'll want to leave `items` intact without removing any Items, so I'd suggest creating a second List called `finalItems`, which will contain your 5 random Items.

```
public List<Item> items;
public List<Item> finalItems;

#region Unity
void Start ()
{
    Screen.lockCursor = true;

    // Do a while loop until finalItems contains 5 Items
    while (finalItems.Count < 5) {
        Item newItem = items[Random.Range(0, items.Count)];
        if (!finalItems.Contains(newItem)) {
            finalItems.Add(newItem);
        }
    }
}
```

And then in your `foreach` statements, loop through `finalItems` instead of `items`.

This will give you 5 random Items every game!

Comment: I think your script works its just not displaying the names of the items. Would I have to make another class for finalItems, so that way I can make a variable to put in my GUI?

Comment: Im still not able to get it to randomize I dont know if Im doing this wrong. I replaced all the items in the foreach statements with finalItems and plug the rest of your code in but I'm not able to see in randomizing.

Comment: I'm just going off your code above, I haven't tested it. I *think* the randomness would work. If you inspect your RayCasting component during runtime, does `finalItems` contain 5 items? Are they random? If you want to ensure that `items` is no longer used (incase you're using it elsewhere), you could call `items.Clear()` at the end of the `Start` function to help throw any errors. The randomness should be there with `finalItems` since that's what `Random.Range` is all about.